# AngularJS view without controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-view

I creating a simple angularjs app. I've imported ngRoute module and 2 views - Home and Contact. Home view is defined with controller.

```
.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "home/home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
})
```

I don't need to implement logic for Contact view, because there are only 1 form to contact with me, that can work very well without angular. Can I define a route view without controller? Like:

```
.when("/contact". {
    templateUrl: "contact/contact.html"
})
```

Is controller obligatory?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It works, but I'm not sure it is correct

Answer (score 3):

No controller is not obligatory. You can define a route without it